# Direct project URL on subscriptions

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I need to create subscriptions and set the pushEndpoint to an App Engine file.

I tried, but to no avail:

```
$subscription->create([
    'pushConfig' => [
        'pushEndpoint' => '/app/site/server.php'
    ]
]);
```

The 'site' folder is the value that is defined in my app.yaml for runtime_config > document_root.

It only accepts HTTP URLs.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you can only push PubSub message to a HTTP endpoint. So, on your AppEngine, expose an endpoint which perform the process and then configure the souscription to call it.